# "Not long ago" vs. "until recently"

Tags: difference

Could you you tell me if there is any difference meaning between *not long ago* and *until recently*? For example:

> **Not long ago**, I would have thought it was impossible to build such a building.
>
> **Until recently**, I would have thought it was impossible to build such a building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this usage, there's no difference. I have not come up with a usage where these would mean different things, or in fact where they can't be swapped for each other.

Comment: Surely _not long ago_ can also mean _recently_ (as distinct from _until recently_)?

Comment: Well, let's see: "Recently, I would have thought it impossible..." -- that seems to *still* mean the same thing. Yes, I agree 'not long ago' can mean that, but not with the implication that it's different. It is a less natural way to put it than the other two, I think.